# CDI Query Module in weblogic 12c (12.1.3)

Tags: java, weblogic, cdi

I am developing an app to be deployed in weblogic 12 and I want to use CDI Query Module in my Dao's https://ctpconsulting.github.io/query/1.0.0.Alpha5/index.html

But cdi-query-imple depends on solder-api and solder-impl 3.1.0.Final and when I try to deploy the app in the app server I get the following exception caused for a jboss class:

```
weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.ComplianceException: AroundInvoke method passExceptionsToSolderCatch in class org.jboss.solder.exception.control.ExceptionHandledInterceptor must have the signature: 'Object <METHOD(InvocationContext)> throws Exception'
    at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.BusinessMethodInterceptorChecker.validateAroundInvokeOrTimeoutMethod(BusinessMethodInterceptorChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.BusinessMethodInterceptorChecker.checkAroundInvokeOrTimeoutMethods(BusinessMethodInterceptorChecker.java:70)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.InterceptorChecker.checkAroundInvokeMethods(InterceptorChecker.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.EJBComplianceChecker.check(EJBComplianceChecker.java:100)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.EJBComplianceChecker.checkDeploymentInfo(EJBComplianceChecker.java:84)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompiler.java:172)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:346)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:314)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileJar(EJBDeployer.java:429)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileIfNecessary(EJBDeployer.java:355)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:723)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:439)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Any chance to run CDI Query Module in weblogic 12?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the error is self-explanatory. The solder module has defined an interceptor and annotated a method with '@AroundInvoke' whose signature does not comply with the specs

> (section 2.5 of Interceptor Specs)
>
> Lifecycle callback interceptor methods defined on an interceptor class
>   must have one of the following  signatures:
>
> - void (InvocationContext)
> - Object (InvocationContext) throws Exception

Answer (score 0):

CTP's Query module has been moved in to Apache DeltaSpike.  Please use the Apache DeltaSpike version for WebLogic.